# Как можно удалить символы в одинаковых классах без замещения с помощью .text()? код внутри

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код который удаляет определённые символы (в частности "руб") в одинаковых классах.

```
var str = $('.block').text();
var result = str.match( /руб/i );
str = str.split(result)[0];
$('.block').text(
function() {
$(this).text(str);
}
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ms2d2nnd/

проблема в том что происходит замещение текста из первого класса во всех остальных. как можно это изменить что бы текст не замещался?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName('block')].forEach(el => 
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace('руб', '')
);
```

```html
<div class="block">123 руб</div>
<div class="block">321 руб</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае неверно используется [метод `.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Геттер возвращает все тексты склеенные в один.

Но сеттер проходит по каждому элементу в наборе.

Далее неверно используется сеттер принимающий функцию.

Вместо кода указанного в вопросе, надо было просто вернуть новое значение для свойства.

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```
$('.block').text(function(index, oldText) {
    return oldText.split( /руб/i )[0]
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Скажите а что это за параметр index у функции?

Comment: @Маркус, индекс элемента в коллекции, которую вернула `$('.block')`